# Intento crear un View Pero dos columnas me dan lo mismo despues de un inner join

Tags: mysql

Al crear una view y hacer inner join para poner los nombres de los equipos me pone los mismos nombres en ambas columnas
ntente crear la view con un inner join pero me arroja lo mismo en ambas columnas:
'''

```
DROP VIEW if exists FaseGrupos;
CREATE VIEW FaseGrupos AS 
    SELECT Partidos.PartidoNum AS '#P',
            Partidos.IdEq1 AS 'Id de Equipo 1',
            Equipos.Equipo AS 'Nombre Eq1',
            Partidos.IdEq2 AS 'Id de Equipo 2',
            Equipos.Equipo AS 'Nombre Eq2'
            FROM Partidos
            INNER JOIN Equipos ON Partidos.IdEq1 = Equipos.IdEquipo;
```

'''

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Te trae el mismo nombre porque tu referencia es la misma, hacia el IdEq1, agrega otro join para que traigas la informacion de IdEq2

```
SELECT 
  Partidos.PartidoNum AS '#P',
  Partidos.IdEq1 AS 'Id de Equipo 1',
  E1.Equipo AS 'Nombre Eq1',
  Partidos.IdEq2 AS 'Id de Equipo 2',
  E2.Equipo AS 'Nombre Eq2'
FROM Partidos
INNER JOIN Equipos as E1 ON Partidos.IdEq1 = E1.IdEquipo
INNER JOIN Equipos as E2 ON Partidos.IdEq2 = E2.IdEquipo;
```